# onetime login in fragmentactivity

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to Android. In my app I created an activity with mutiplefragment.
In my app, I am displaying first screen as login screen. If a username and a password are entered it should display my home fragment, otherwise it should display the login screen. How to do this by using shared preferences? Can anyone help me?
Below is my code :

LOGINFRAGMENT:

```
public void setLoginScreen(String usename, String password) {
    String userName = Mainactivity._sharedPreferences.getString("userName", "null");
    Editor editor = Mainactivity._sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("userName", username);
    editor.putString("Pass", password);
    if (customerSNo.equals(username)) {
    } else {
        editor.putBoolean("loginStatus", false);
    }
    editor.commit();

}
```

If false it will launch the login screen, but if true how to launch the home screen?

Comment: You can create an activity for login because it has seperate logic. You should not use fragment for login, you can create another activity (container) for fragments. If you new to android, you should look activity and fragment lifecycles

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to show Login Fragment when a user is not logged in and direct him to the Home Fragment when he is not logged in.

What you need to implement:
1) After app starts, In you MainActivity (I suppose it manages your fragments) check whether the user is logged in:

```
String userName = sharedPreferences.getString("userName", null);
```

2) If it is not empty we assume that user's authorization is valid and we can show HomeFragment: (This code is in MainActivity) https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=en

```
HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

3) Otherwise, (if there is no username) show LoginFragment (like at example above)

4) At LoginFragment when user clicks 'Login' button, take the data from the form (login and password), verify it and if it's valid, add a username to SharedPreferences (this way, next time when your app starts, it will know the user and direct him to the HomeFragment).

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString("userName", username).commit();
```

5) After you verified the login data and stored it in SharedPreferences, you need to show HomeFragment (look example above).

Proposed approach is eligible only for test project purposes, it's not good practice to determine the state of user login only by the username value in shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a function to check the login status in shared preferences and if status is true fire intent for starting activity else don't fire intent and ask to login

```
//inside onCreate()
setContentView(R.layout.name_of_xml);
//initialize your shared preferences object
//call to login check function
//rest of code.....
```

create a function like this :

```
private void checkLogin(){
    if(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("status",false)){
        //(if true) , i.e user is already logged in
        //fire intent for home activity or 
        //begin home fragment transaction

    } else{
        //(if false),i.e user is not logged in
        //fire intent for login activity or
        //begin home fragment transaction
    }
}
```